# How to read TFRecords from S3 with tensorflow_io for training a model

Tags: amazon-s3, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

I was using `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` for reading the TFRecords from GCS (temporarily) but now I need to use AWS S3 and when I read the TFRecords using the same function, it shows `UnimplementedError - File system scheme 's3' not implemented`.

On further investigation, I discovered that all the modular filesystems have been moved to another library `tensorflow_io`. From whatever I have gathered from the docs/tutorials etc., it seems that we just need to import this library and it should work with the other filesystems. But for me it is still not working and throws `UnimplementedError`

I'm using the tensorflow version 2.8.2

Comment: Hey, currently having the same problem. Have you solved the issue?